# How to check if any argument in Union[...] is None in python?

Tags: python, union

I want to filter code where any of the argument in Union[..] is None. What is the best way to identify None arguments?

I know that the order of arguments does not matter in Union[](from typing import Union) but how do I a common check(possibly a function) to detect None arguments.

```
from typing import Union
Union[T, None]
```

Comment: Closely related/possible dupe: [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/48572831)

Comment: What exactly do you want to filter, things that are annotated with `Union[T, None]`? The value of the expression `Union[T, None]` has an `__args__` attribute that contains the `None` type.

Comment: @chepner Only upwards of 3.5. Pre-3.6 it's `__union_params__`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function property `__annotations__`:

```
def my_func(a: Union[int, None], b: int, c: str):
    print(a,b,c)

print(my_func.__annotations__) # {'a': typing.Union[int, NoneType], 'b': <class 'int'>, 'c': <class 'str'>}
```

Now we can do something to check it programatically:

```
from typing import _GenericAlias

def check_if_func_accepts_none(func):
    for key in func.__annotations__:
        if isinstance(func.__annotations__[key], type(None)):
            return True
        elif isinstance(func.__annotations__[key], _GenericAlias) and type(None) in func.__annotations__[key].__args__:
            return True
    return False
```

Examples:

```
>>> def b(a:int, b:None):
...     print('hi')
...
>>> def c(x:Union[None,str], y:int):
...     print('hi')
...
>>> def d(z: int, s:str):
...     print('hi')
...
>>> check_if_func_accepts_none(b)
True
>>> check_if_func_accepts_none(c)
True
>>> check_if_func_accepts_none(d)
False
>>>
```

EDIT: To answer your comment, to check `Union` objects directly:

```
type(None) in obj.__args__
```

This would return `True` if `None` is there and `False` otherwise (assuming `obj` is a `Union`)

Comment: I wanted to check the arguments of Union itself. Thanks:)